# Perl Recurse through Directory

Tags: perl, directory

So essentially what I'm trying to do is go through a directory and perform an action on all of the files, in this case, the sub searchForErrors.  This sub works.  What I have so far is:

```
sub proccessFiles{
    my $path = $ARGV[2];

    opendir(DIR, $path) or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
    my @files = readdir(DIR);
    @files = map{$path . '/' . $_ } @files;
    closedir(DIR);

    for (@files){
        if(-d $_){
            process_files($_);
        }
        else{
        searchForErrors;
    }
}
}

proccessFiles($path);
```

Any help/suggestions would be great.  And again, I'm new to Perl, so the more explanation the better.  Thank you!

Comment: My question is that the code I posted does not compile.  What am I doing wrong/missing?  Or is there an easier way to recurse through directories?

Comment: You should `use strict; use warnings;` and post your errors. Yes, there is an easier way, using the File::Find module as demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) module instead of trying to reinvent the wheel:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @files;
my $start_dir = "somedir";  # top level dir to search
find( 
    sub { push @files, $File::Find::name unless -d; }, 
    $start_dir
);
for my $file (@files) {
    searchForErrors($file); 
}
```

A problem with your current code is that you are including `.` and `..` directories in your recursive search, which will no doubt cause `deep recursion` errors.

Comment: Just another quick question to double check.  In line five, when I am putting in the top level to search, do I need to include all of the path, like C:\folder\directory?

Comment: @user1440061 That depends on from which directory you are calling the script. If you call the script from `c:\perl`, you'll need to specify full path, or a correct relative path. If you are calling it from `c:\folder\directory`, you only need `.` for current directory.

Comment: Another question - what is the @files for?  I.e. what is it's purpose in this code?  Just trying to make sure I fully understand all of this

Comment: @user1440061 It's purpose is storing the file names found by `File::Find`.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be useful to show a [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass) solution in addition to TLP's [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) one.

I think this is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class 'dir';

my $root = dir 'C:\path\to\root';

$root->recurse(callback => sub {
  my $file = shift;
  searchForErrors($file) unless $file->is_dir;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was very helpful!  Can't tell you how much I appreciate it!

Comment: When I implement that code, in the cmd I get an error saying "Can't locate Path/Class.pm in @INC.  Any thoughts?!

Comment: You need to install the module. Probably using CPAN. Take a look at [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html).

Answer (score 1):

A better way of using `File::Find` without using a lot of memory would be:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;

find(
    sub { 
        searchForErrors($File::Find::name) unless -d
    }, 
    "/tmp/"
);
```

This is more iterator style.